# Java Math Formula for calculating body fat percentages

Tags: java

Not sure why but I'm struggling to write this formula...

```
Double bf = 163.205 * log10(waist + hip - neck) - 97.684 * log10(height) - 78.387
```

It's the correct formula used to calculate body fat percentages. If I used various websites I have been able to get a sensible answer but in Java I seem to getting a minus answer.

`Website
e.g waist = 29, hip = 38, neck = 12, height = 187`

The order of mathmatics is incorrect when programming. How should this be wrote?

Here is a working version:

http://fitness.bizcalcs.com/Calculator.asp?Calc=Body-Fat-Navy

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*order of mathematics is incorrect*"?

Comment: I used a calculator and am also getting a negative answer (-16.274) with those values. Aren't you confusing inches and centimeters?

Comment: @PM77-1 I am sure he means operator precedence, but doesn't know the technical term.  Phil's likely thinking that some mathematical operations are being applied in ways that are incongruous with how they would be applied by a mathematician.  Java's precedence is compatible with most major math notations.  The problem was found to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you're using uses inches, while you're using centimeters.

Comment: Addendum: https://www.calculatorpro.com/calculator/us-navy-body-fat-calculator/ has formulas for inches and centimeters, for men as well as women.

Comment: What a rookie mistake I have made!!!! I thought I had checked that but my conversions were incorrect!

Comment: It looks like OP is using a mixture of inches and centimeters (29 cm waist would be pretty darn thin).

Answer (score 1):

This formula is for US Metrics, you use SI metrics values

For SI metrics you need:

for men: 86.010*log10(waist-neck) - 70.041*log10(height) + 30.30

for female: 163.205*log10(waist + hip - neck) - 97.684*log10(height) - 104.912